# Index in partitioned table

Tags: mysql, indexing

How MySQL create index for a partition table, Example if I create 5 hash by ID  partitions:

- Create 1 global index for all data and 5 partitions will use this index
- Create 5 partitioned index with subdata in 5 partitioned tables
- Create 5 index with all data in 5 partitioned tables

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no "global" index for a partitioned table in MySQL.

The only indexes you can put on a partitioned table ends up being separate indexes on each partition.  Each partition is effectively an independent table.

HASH partitioning is virtually useless; do you have a particular use for which you think it might be beneficial?

Addenda...

The size of the index is similar to that of a table.

Since there are no "global" indexes, you cannot have a `UNIQUE` key unless it includes the column(s) of the "partition key".  Nor can you use `FOREIGN KEYs`.

There is no type of index that spans more than one table.

Comment: The reason is knowing how MySQL create index on partitioned table  help me to know clear about how it working and help me to estimate the size or tuning the performance.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioned table in Mysql has only local indexes support. 
What does that mean? Every partition of the table stores its own B-Tree for the indexes. This can slow down the process of search if you don't have partition key as part of the index. Also for unique key constraint, you need to add partition key as part of the unique key.

Compared to Mysql, Oracle has concept of Global indexes as well. Global Indexes are very hard to manage.

I am not too sure How helpful Mysql partitions would be if it has ignored Global indexes.

Comment: "This can slow down the process of search if you don't have partition key as part of the index" – how's that? If you have the partition key as part of your WHERE clause, *partition pruning* already narrows it down to the corresponding partition(s). And if not, due to the nature of the index being partitioned, all index partitions have to be looked up anyway. So wouldn't including the partition key unnecessarily enlarge the index, and thus the opposite being true – or did I miss something here?

Comment: Agreed but we are taking the case where our search is on the index where Partition Key is not part of. In that case, DB Engine will have to search for the key in all the partitions as MySql does not have concept of Global Index.

Comment: You mean if the WHERE does not include the "partition key" but the PK (e.g. PK is `id`, partition key is `created_date`, and WHERE has only something like `id between 100 and 500`)? Then indeed it had to parse as many indexes as there are partitions, right. But with `id between 100 and 500 and created_date = $x` it wouldn't matter if `created_date` is in some index – thanks to pruning only the relevant partition would be scanned. But yes, one must consider that when "planning".